# Unit testing an implementation of IExpectException

Tags: nunit

I've created an expected exception attribute by implementing the `NUnit.Framework.IExpectException` interface, as documented there (http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=exception&r=2.6.2 ) and it works pretty well. It validates that the thrown exception is of the right type and validates the value of some properties on the exception.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class ExpectedHttpErrorExceptionAttribute : ExpectedExceptionAttribute, IExpectException
{
    public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; set; }

    public ExpectedHttpErrorExceptionAttribute()
        :base(typeof(HttpError))
    {}

    public ExpectedHttpErrorExceptionAttribute(HttpStatusCode statusCode)
        :this()
    {
        StatusCode = statusCode;
    }

    public void HandleException(Exception ex)
    {
        Assert.That(ex, Is.TypeOf(ExpectedException), "Expected exception of type '{0}' but an exception of type '{1}' has been throwned.", typeof(HttpError).FullName, ex.GetType().FullName);

        var httpStatusCode = ((HttpError) ex).StatusCode;
        Assert.That(httpStatusCode, Is.EqualTo(StatusCode), "Expected status code '{0}' but was '{1}'.", StatusCode, httpStatusCode);

    }
}
```

My problem is that I want to unit test that attribute, but I can't figure a way to test the following case :

`A unit test that have the attribute should fail if no exception are thrown.`

I just can't figure a way to write a unit test for that case, since the HandleException is not called when no exception are thrown.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are failing to write a test here is that you are trying to test functionality which is out of responsibility of your class.

Your class validates the exception only in case if exception is thrown. When there is no exception thrown there is nothing to validate :)

It is responsibility of *test runner* (NUnit or some another) to fail the test when test method is decorated with `ExpectedExceptionAttribute` (or inherited attribute) and there is no exception thrown during test.

So, you don't need to write a test fot such a scenario.